# Spring Boot @Value is null, cant be solved with @Component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a bean in my spring boot project that needs to return one or the other depending on what settings are provided in an external application.properties file.

The setting that will always exist is "type". Each of the 2 types implement "SomeInterface", but have their own unique settings from the properties file to be fetched.

```
@Bean
public SomeInterface someinterface(){

    switch(type) {
        case "type1":
            return new Type1();
        case "type2":
            return new Type2();
        default:
            throw Exception
    }
}
```

```
public class Type1 implements SomeInterface {

    @Value("${some.property}")
    private String property1;   //Always null

    @Value("${some.property2}")
    private String property2;   //Always null
}
```

I've looked around and it seems I cant fetch the values using `@Value` within each of the two types because of the class being instantiated with `new`. Other posts I've seen fix this issue use `@Component` to have spring instantiate the bean for you, but this doesnt work in my case. When properties for 1 type exists, the properties for the other will not. Is there a simple way to be able to fetch these properties with `@Value` in each of the type classes while also only instantiating the type that is needed instead of trying to instantiate both?

Comment: You can add the values as parameters of the bean method and use them in the creation of the appropriate class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring is not going to process those annotations unless you let it do the instantiation. You will want to use the application context like so.

```
@Bean
public SomeInterface someinterface(){

    @Autowired private ApplicationContext context;

    switch(type) {
        case "type1":
            return context.getBean(Type1.class);
        case "type2":
            return context.getBean(Type2.class);
        default:
            throw Exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do this but create the bean as well? The overall issue was errors being thrown if spring tried to instantiate both Type1 and Type2 as beans, while the properties only exist for one or the other. I'd get errors from @Value fields being null

Comment: Since `Type1` and `Type2` are different classes, each should request only what it needs. So only `property1` in the class for `Type1`. (I am not sure that answers your question)

Comment: I fixed the issue by adding Component and Lazy to each of the classes, I did want it to fetch the existing bean, the bean just wasnt being created on startup because it was missing annotations. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is a somewhat risky thing to do because it relies on the `TypeX` classes already having been instantiated when the `@Configuration` containing the `@Bean` is evaluated.

The canonical way to do this is to not declare the implementing classes as `@Component`s if you declare them as `@Bean`s anyway, but to create them in the `@Bean` method.

```
@Configuration
class MyBeans {
 @Bean
 SomeInterface(@Value(@Value("${some.property}") prop1, 
                      @Value("${some.property2}") prop2) {
  var type = ...; // not clear where this comes from in your example

  SomeInterface result;
  switch(type) {
   case "type1": return new Type1(prop1, prop2);
   case "type2": return new Type2(prop1, prop2);
   default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot evaluate type");
  }
 }
}
```